# What is the maximum, allowable field length for a FacilityID field in a Cityworks geodatabase?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, extensions, cmms, database-model

Over the past couple of months, I have seen a few [esri-geodatabase](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esri-geodatabase)s and they seem to be either a text field with a length of 20 or 30.  Is 30 the maximum field length?

Clarification:
The answer I'm looking for is if there is a Cityworks-specific constraint on the text field length in the esri geodatabase.

Comment: Maybe extension-specific questions should not be on this site or did I ask this question poorly??

Comment: See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269/are-questions-regarding-3rd-party-esri-extensions-appropriate-for-this-site in meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was forwarded an email from a Cityworks CST  stating the max field length for a Cityworks FacilityID field is **50**.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/file_g-1445296021.htm), the maximum text field length for a file geodatabase is about 2GB. (Not that I've tried that, of course, but I've seen fields as long as 1024 characters.)

UPDATE: If Cityworks Geodatabase is a personal geodatabase (based on MS Access), then the maximum character length for a Text field is 255. See [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n0000004q000000.htm) (at the very bottom).

Comment: So if I specify a FacilityID of 1024 (not that I would actually do that), Cityworks will accept it?  I'll update the question and try to clarify the question.

Comment: @Jay Why not just try that to see whether it works? :-)

Comment: At the time, we didn't have actually have Cityworks, but had selected Cityworks (govt red-tape at work).  We were creating new featureclasses that we knew would be used in Cityworks. I don't work there anymore, but they still don't have Cityworks--red-tape was extra sticky.

Comment: btw, Cityworks says the max field length for a FacilityID field is 50. I mentioned it as a comment and thought someone else would make an answer out of it, but it's been long enough so I'll do it!